# Unable to restore from file postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dump

I am trying to restore a database from file. Here is my file 
http://pastebin.com/JSmG0Htm
I am running

```
 psql db_name < path_to_file
```

and here is error message
http://pastebin.com/cqDYxUUM
What is the problem . ???
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to restore dumps made that way with pg_restore, not psql.

Comment: I tried to make it from phpPgAdmin (not manually ) but I got the same errors . I assume the way of executing the statement does not matter

Comment: I don't know what statement you're talking about.  The dump you've provided cannot be restored with psql -- you must use pg_restore, which is a different program.

Answer (score 0):

Use command as this.

```
psql -f path_to_file db_name
```

It should work